# How to get the last url in a chain of redirects in vueJS

Tags: vue.js, redirect

I'm trying to follow through on a url that redirects me to another page using VueJS.

Combing through the docs I could not find anything that allows me to retrieve the last url after the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `document.referrer`, it returns the URI of the page that linked to the current page.

If you're using VueRouter, you can also check https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Comment: i mean i want to go back to internal web page after accessing some chained external redirect page, is it possible?

Comment: Does `history.back()` suit you?